# CSS, how to change the background after a certain time and keep it like that

Tags: html, css

When i run this the color will change after 5 seconds but after the 5 seconds it goes back to White, however i want it to stay #1b1b1b

```
.bg {
  -webkit-animation: change-color 5s; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    change-color 5s; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      change-color 5s; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         change-color 5s; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

And

```
@-webkit-keyframes change-color {
 from {
        background: White;
 }
 to {
        background: #1b1b1b;
 }
}
(I also use -moz-animation etc)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `forwards` to you animation declaration:

```css
.bg {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-animation: change-color 5s forwards;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: change-color 5s forwards;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: change-color 5s forwards;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: change-color 5s forwards;
  /* IE 10+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes change-color {
  from {
    background: white;
  }
  to {
    background: #1b1b1b;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Please notice that `background: White` is invalid but `background: white` is.

Comment: will just add that the property long-hand is animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Comment: @Timvanderploeg No problem please don't `validate` the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `transition`.

```
body {
    background: red;
    transition: background 5s linear;
}

.recolor {
    background: black;
}
```

Adding the class `recolor` to the `body` will change the color from `red` to `black`.